# redirect in htaccess with partly remove of a weblink

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using simple mod-rewrite rule:

```
Redirect 301 /feeds/ https://some-interesting-website.../feed/index.php
```

It doesn't work because if I have some link: 
/feeds/some-difficulf-link/many-files-and-folders.php  than result is:

```
https://some-interesting-website.../feed/index.phpsome-difficult-link/many-files-and-folders.php
```

How could I remove a rest of a link after index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really hard job. I was need to pay a lot of time and efforts in it to find a solution.

Looks like mod rewrite logic is not very clear. However this code worked perfect for me: `Redirect 301 /feeds https://some-interesting-website.../feed/index.php?`